NetSuite Permission For CSV Import of Bins
I need to setup a User Role with permission to import Bins, but I can't seem to find the right combination of permissions. This is a "Power User" role, so most things are set to Full permission, including:

Bins
CSV Import
Setup CSV Import Preference

I've run a role comparison between admin and this role and don't see anything obvious that I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated!

Just found that the "Accounting Lists" permission "Allows viewing and editing of the Bin record." Adding that permission allows user to import Bins.
